Creating library using Cython and getting link error
I have to create a windows library from python code. To hide my source code, I want to cythonize the code and create a single library which can be used by everyone.
My folder structure
manager/
├── sample/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── a.py
│   ├── b.py
│   └── c.py
│       
│── __init__.py
├── main.py  
└── setup.py  # For building the shared library

a.py -
class a:
    def test(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclasses should implement this!")

b.py -
from sample import a

class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        return

    def test(self):
        return True

c.py -
from sample import a

class c(a):
    def __init__(self):
        return

    def test(self):
    
    return True

init.py and main.py are empty files
I am using Visual Studio code.
When I run this command : python setup.py build_ext --inplace , I get error :
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit_sample
build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\temp_build\sample\sample.cp312-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
My setup.py :
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

def find_py_files():
    current_dir = os.getcwd()  # Use current directory
    print(f"Searching for Python files in: {current_dir}")
    files = []
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(current_dir):
        if 'venv' in root:  # Ignore the venv directory
            continue
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(".py") and filename != "__init__.py" and filename != "setup.py":  # Skip __init__.py files
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                print(f"Found: {os.path.relpath(file_path, start=current_dir)}")
                files.append(file_path)
    return files

temp_build_dir = "temp_build"

# Combine all found Python files into a single extension module
py_files = find_py_files()
if py_files:
    extension = Extension(
        name = "sample",
        sources = py_files,
        language='c++'
    )

    setup(
        name='sample',
        ext_modules=cythonize(
            [extension],
            build_dir=temp_build_dir,
            ),
        zip_safe=False,
    )
else:
    print("No Python files found to compile.")

My issue is that .pyd is only not getting created. The Collapse multiple submodules to one Cython extension tells about import from cython modules after pyd is created

The basic problem that you're experiencing is: each source file will create it's own module init function. So a.py will create PyInit_a and b.py will create PyInit_b. When you try to create an extension module called sample it needs there to be a function called PyInit_sample. This function doesn't exist because there's no source file for it. Both Python and Cython work on the basis that "one file" == "one module" and the filename gives the module name. You're trying to do something that was never intended
